# Animating Hub's scrolling

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I've written an *Attached Property* to be able to bind the index of the displayed `HubSection` to my *ViewModel*, so that I can change it within my code.

I'm using the `Hub`'s `ScrollTo(section)` method but it doesn't animate the scroll, so I decided to use the `ScrollViewer` inside the `Hub` with the `ChangeView` method.

What happens is that, having 4 `HubSection`, it just scrolls to the second one before hanging.

The `viewer.HorizontalOffset` stays **fixed** at `360` (which is the `HubSection`'s `ActualWidth`) and there's no way to change it!

Here's the code that I'm using to animate the scroll:

```
async private static Task ScrollHubToSection(Hub hub, HubSection section, int index)
{
    var dispatcher = hub.Dispatcher;            
    var viewer = hub.GetDescendantsOfType<ScrollViewer>().First();
    var offset = index*section.ActualWidth;                   
    await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => viewer.ChangeView(offset, null, null, false));
}
```

(`GetDescendantsOfType` is from `WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Extensions`)

What I'd expect is that calling

```
ScrollHubSection(myHub, section1, 1)
```

should scroll the `viewer` to an `HorizontalOffset` of `360`, while

```
ScrollHubSection(myHub, section2, 2)
```

(with `offset` becomes correctly `720`) still leaves `HorizontalOffset` to `360` which is quite nonsens.

If I manually insert the offset by doing

```
viewer.ChangeView(1000, null, null, false));
```

it goes to an `HorizontalOffset` of `1000`, but if I do

```
viewer.ChangeView(offset, null, null, false));
```

when `offset` is `1000` it doesn't work.

This is really driving me mad because I've wasted the whole afternoon trying to fix it without success.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
async private static Task ScrollHubToSection(Hub hub, HubSection section, int index)
{
    var dispatcher = hub.Dispatcher;            
    var viewer = hub.GetDescendantsOfType<ScrollViewer>().First();
    double offset = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        offset += hub.Sections[i].ActualWidth;
    }                  
    await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => viewer.ChangeView(offset, null, null, false));
}
```